Is an extension cord contaminated with liquefied ice melt safe?
I had a bag of ice melt that ripped and then turned to liquid. It got on a fabric extension cord in the process. I imagine I should toss the extension cord. If so, what's the best way to get rid of it? It doesn't seem safe to just toss a potential fire hazard in the regular trash.

how is it a fire hazard?

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement per the [help].

I'd just wash it up and put it back into service. I stand in firm opposition to our modern throwaway society, which the planet cannot sustain.
Soak it in a mild soap solution for a few hours. Shake it off and hang it outside to dry for a few more hours. Now look it over. If the contacts in the female plug aren't corroded, it's good to go in my book. If they are, toss it in the regular trash. There's no chemical or fire hazard here.

Relax, The cord is not a fire hazard unless it is plugged in, and then only if it is frayed and or misused. In my area of the world, you can throw it out in regular trash, not in recycling. (In recycling it is what is referred to as a "tangler" and can get caught in machinery.)
There is no danger in an extention cord if it is not plugged in and not in the hands of a nefarious person.

In large parts of the world, electrical waste would be correct place...

I did not know no danger in an extension cord if it is not plugged in 

If one is really concerned about someone else using it after it is disposed of, cut the plug & socket ends off the cable, smash the living daylights out of the cut-off plug & socket ends with a hammer so they'll never fit any known electrical standard's plugs & sockets ever again, and toss the whole kaboodle.

Do not put electrical waste in regular trash.

@Pete, that is exactly where a discarded extension cord goes in my part of the world.

It should not be put in regular trash wherever you live. Just because your government (or whoever is encouraging you to do this) are failing doesn't mean you should encourage people to fail too.

@ Pete, You can suggest to place electrical trash  wherever you wish. However it is not up to you to police the rules that each of us have as to what trash goes where.  It is common and normal where I live. You may suggest otherwise, and give some reason/s as to why, However casting aspersions is just rude.

@PeteKirkham As I understand it, generally speaking (but yes, can vary by jurisdiction), the concern is not "anything electrical". Rather it is *electronics" that often (but not always) include one or more of: lead, batteries (lithium, NiCad, lead acid, etc. - all have serious concerns), components with other toxic chemicals (e.g., some capacitors) and so on. An extension cord is generally no more than copper + rubber or plastic. Nothing more toxic or dangerous there than in a lot of toys or furniture or other generic "trash".

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the insulation will very likely be PVC with fire retardants, which become an environmental toxin when released by incineration or leaching in landfill. The copper is a fairly valuable metal that can be easily recycled, which e-waste companies will do. Yes, lots of toys and furniture are also made of PVC and should be dealt with safely; unfortunately it's harder to do so as you can't sell the copper content to mitigate the costs.
